# java irc Dice bot not working

Tags: java, irc, bots, dice

Im trying to make a java bot that connects to an IRC, and then when a user types a command, it "rolls dice" but it seems to not be working

```
cannot find symbol variable IntRoll
illegal start of type
cannot find symbol variable OpRoll
illegal start of type
cannot find symbol variable Op
cannot find symbol variable IntRoll
illegal start of type
cannot find symbol variable OpRoll
illegal start of type
cannot find symbol variable Op
cannot find symbol variable Op
cannot find symbol variable generator
int cannot be dereferenced
cannot return a value from method whose result type is void
int cannot be dereferenced
cannot return a value from method whose result type is void
cannot return a value from method whose result type is void
cannot return a value from method whose result type is void
cannot find symbol variable generator
cannot find symbol variable InRoll
cannot return a value from method whose result type is void
cannot find symbol variable InRoll
cannot return a value from method whose result type is void
cannot return a value from method whose result type is void
```

here are the two files,
   http://pastebin.com/c47RqRsd
   http://pastebin.com/v4Y42uF4

Comment: tried compiling using javac through cmd, still got those errors

Comment: Yes, your code has compiler errors in it. You will get those errors no matter which compiler you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems with `roll`:

- You cannot return a value from a constructor. Constructors are used to instantiate an object. You should probably create a field and set it to `InRoll`.
- If you're trying to generate a number between 2 and 12 with dice, that's not the way to do it. You will get an unrealistic distribution where you get more 2's than normal.
- You cannot invoke a method on a primitive type. You should be using `InRoll == someNumber`.
- You cannot return a value in a method if its return type is `void`.
- You did not create a field named `InRoll`, so you cannot use it in your `onMessage` method.

Problems with `Dice4Cash`:

- You cannot access a field that does not exist. You create neither an `IntRoll` field nor an `OpRoll` field.

I highly suggest you walk your way through some Java tutorials and learn the language.
[Getting Started](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html).
[Learning the Java Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html).